# generate xml files with Google cloud dataflow

Tags: xml, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am working on a project to generate xml files that contains data that will be displayed on Google Maps.

The tables are stored on the cloud BigQuery. We create our own queries for these tables.

How can I automate the launching of queries on BigQuery via google Cloud DataFlow, knowing that we will have a parameter table?

Is it possible to generate an xml file with Google Cloud DataFlow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to identify options for interacting with XML in Dataflow/Beam, this would help:

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/xml/XmlIO.html

For interacting with BigQuery:

1. Review the Beam programming guide:
   https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/
2. For interacting with BigQuery, check the javadoc:
   https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/

Comment: Thanks @Yuri for your help
i want know: How can I automate the launching of queries on BigQuery via google Cloud DataFlow

Comment: Updated answer - see if this helps?